# Free Web hosting for web applications

Tags: web-hosting

Are there web sites that offers hosting of a web application that uses c++? I know that there are a lot of free web hosting solutions that offers hosting for regular web applications made with php, mysql, etc. I would like to upload a routing engine for my website. My application is a travel planner, and I have a custom routing engine that is made of c++. If there are free online Linux OS hosting that can act as a ordinary OS installation (which will be my best option), I would greatly appreciate if you can list them below. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your main site hosted?

Answer (score 1):

With hosting costs coming down drastically over the years, it really doesn't make sense to gamble with a free hosting provider anymore. You should consider spending a few dollars and buy a decent hosting space. Amazon EC2, Dreamhost, GoDaddy, Linode, Slicehost etc. are good economical options to choose from. It also guarantees better uptime and performance.

Comment: GoDaddy sucks. I've tried them VERY slow. They are also NOT cheap, $60 or more for a year of hosting.

Answer (score 1):

[Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) if free for one year. They support c++, so you can try it out. After that, though, you start paying.